# how to access samba share from Windows which is running on different port

Tags: samba, defaults

I have samba server already running on standard ports(445 and 139). This samba server is integrated in Alfresco application. I need to setup new samba server but now I have problem with ports. Ok, so in my `smb.conf` I put this option

```
smb ports = 450 140
```

Restart samba

```
/etc/init.d/samba restart
```

I have

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/samba# netstat -na |grep 450
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:450             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

but
how to connect to samba share folder from windows machine on port different then standard samba port?

Answer (score 8):

This **can't** be done.  Windows does not support TCP ports other than 445/139.  [Here is one reference.](http://www.blisstonia.com/eolson/notes/smboverssh.php)

Answer (score 3):

use **NAT**

this can be done by applying some rule on your router/gateway

[windows]--**139**-->[*dst-nat* **139** to x.x.x.x:**1139** router ]-->**1139**-->[samba-server listen on :**1139**]

Answer (score 1):

I have tried different approach, and finally got the solution.
Here's the approach:

1. You need to close the local samba server first.

- `sc config lanmanserver start=disabled`
- `sc stop lanmanserver`
- Reboot

2. Use `netsh interface` command create a new port proxy for this ip.
   If your server ip is ipv6, you should use `v4tov6`, otherwise `v4tov4`. Here my example, assuming your service's port is 1139:

   ```
   netsh interface portproxy add v4tov6 listenport=445 connectaddress=[blah:blah:blah:blah] connectport=1139
   ```
3. You are now able to connect to your samba server via `\\127.0.0.1`

Wish you enjoy the solution!

Comment: I don't know why but after copying around 20 gb of data my pc is completely unresponsive

Answer (score 1):

<sub>@Arjo's answer is useful if you have admin access to an external network, and @linzuojian's is useful if you don't host a samba share already on windows; but you can combine the two using a loopback device to have your cake and eat it too (interestingly @Rahul says it cannot be done, but then links to a really old tutorial on how this was accomplished on XP..)</sub>

[On Windows 10 admin PowerShell](https://gist.github.com/Hashbrown777/081e57ff9673a1f457e1c3a71b55cfaf#file-attachsmb-ps1):

```powershell
iwr `
    'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Hashbrown777/081e57ff9673a1f457e1c3a71b55cfaf/raw/28dcd74be1281812e2ef17b1bd36c6b5db216ca3/attachsmb.ps1' `
    -OutFile attachsmb.ps1
Install-Module -Name LoopbackAdapter -MinimumVersion 1.2.0.0
. './attachsmb.ps1'
Create-Host -Name ubuntusmb -Ip 10.254.0.1 -Dest <#ubuntu's IP#> -Port 450
<#REBOOT#>
explorer \\ubuntusmb
```

This allows you to maintain a native SMB share locally *AND* connect to another on a non-standard port (local or external) only configuring your local machine.

[Basically](https://superuser.com/a/1751207/241800) you give your machine another IP with your new fake network interface, on this new IP you can host on port 445 forwarding to the non-standard server, and finally you can assign this IP any hostname you like with your hosts file.